# Intermittently consuming kafka messages in a springboot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-scheduled

I have the following use-case:

Messages which my application could not process, possibly due to some intermittent issues related to network, etc, are being written to a kafka topic.

I want to periodically read these messages using a cron/scheduled task, and then process them.

So far I've used the  KafkaListener in my springboot for my kafka-related needs, and has worked well.

However, I could not find a way to read messages intermittently using KafkaListener.

Is there even a way to do this in spring? Would be glad if someone could link to documents or tutorials or describe a way to achieve what I want to do.

Comment: Was the answer I posted useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manage consuming process manually. It is possible if you disable `autostartup` feature of `KafkaListener`.

There are two discussions about this. See below:

[Is there any example of Spring Schedule that reads Kafka topic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59260089/is-there-any-example-of-spring-schedule-that-reads-kafka-topic)

[Spring Boot Job scheduler with Kafka consumer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65612527/spring-boot-job-scheduler-with-kafka-consumer)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use idleBetweenPolls parameter, it will allow you to read periodically

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/ContainerProperties.html#setIdleBetweenPolls(long)